# Sublime Text 3: Remove a mis-spelled word the dictionary

Tags: dictionary, sublimetext3, spell-checking

Like a complete pilchard, I've added a misspelling to the default en-GB spellchecking dictionary in Sublime Text.

I've checked online and in the documentation, but nowhere does there seem to be any information about dictionary management

Can anyone tell me how to remove it?

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Sublime Text stores words you add to the dictionary in the User preferences file, under `"added_words"`. You can simply edit this JSON to delete the word you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks. You set me on the right path and eventually I found what I needed under Preferences > Settings. Once again, thank you for your help.